# Getting UID of NDEF tag when scanning NFC tag with AAR Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, nfc, aar

The problem i'm having is i'm trying to open an app when I scan the NFC card, and pass in data to the app immediately. All I need passed in is the ID of the card. I already have this working, kind of. In NFC Tools I add an AAR (Add Application Record) and add the package name, and this opens the app. In my code in android studio I have the following intent

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
```

And in my main activity I have

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        UIDLabel.setText(intent.action.toString())
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED == intent.action) {
            val tag = intent.getParcelableExtra<Tag>(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)
            UIDLabel.setText((ByteUtils.bytesToHex(tag!!.id)))
        }
    }
```

This does return my UID of the Tag but I also need to have a Text record added to the card for it to work (Obviously because the intent-filter is looking for "text/plain". What i'm trying to do is achieve the same results just without the Text having to be added to the card. I've experimented with different intent-filters and nothing works. Does anyone know what intent-filter I should use in this situation? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `*/*` as the mimeType String?

Comment: Just tried, still only seems to work for text assigned to the tag, not empty tags :(

Comment: For empty tags, it would not be an action of `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED` but actions of `ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED` or `ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED`

Comment: @Andrew tried that too but when I do but its only opens the app and the code never gets called :/